# How to copy variable labels from one variable to another

Tags: spss

I have used CTABLES to create a table which is essentially a crosstab of 3 variables with some, but not all, subtotals. 
Using OMS I have saved the resulting table to a SAV-file.
To my surprise the variables with the actual counts are string-variables.
I want to round the counts, so I created numeric variables in the following manner:

```
NumVar = 5*(rnd(numeric(CountVar, F4.0)/5)).
```

Now I would like to copy the variable label of Countvar to Numvar, using syntax. But how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better rounding method, and then the code to copy the label:

```
NumVar = rnd(numeric(CountVar, F4), 5).
apply dictionary from * / source var = CountVar / target var = NumVar / varinfo varlabels.
```

Comment: Yes, I really want to keep CountVar. I need to check all my steps. Overwriting an existing variable or altering it, is not allowed. I need the situation Before and After, so a colleague can check whether my code is working as intended.

Comment: When searching on Internet I did find `apply dicationary`, but it did not mention the varlabels option for varinfo. Thanx!